# prevent PowerDNS to be open_resolver

Tags: powerdns, powerdns-recursor

sorry if my question is too long.

I have 4 PowerDNS servers, as below with sample IPs.
ns1.example.com 1.1.1.1
ns2.example.com 2.2.2.2
rec1.example.com 3.3.3.3
rec2.example.com 4.4.4.4

in my network, ns1 & ns2 are authoritative servers that have some zones and reverse_zones.
and rec1 & rec2 are recursor DNS servers.
I have configured rec1&rec2 to ask for my own zones from ns1&ns2 with "forward-zones" on powerdns/recursor.conf which is work fine.
and also I configure "forward-zones-recurse=.=8.8.8.8" to send all other queries to the google DNS which it works too.
I have so many subnets(clients) in my network that use rec1 & rec2 as their main DNS servers on their machines.
they ask any domain from rec1&rec2 according to the domain the rec1&rec2 ask that query from ns1&ns2 or from google.
to this point I have no problem, my clients can query successfully for any address.

my problem is that my rec1&rec2 became "open_resolver" to the internet, I mean anyone from the internet can send DNS queries to these servers and they work.
I configured "allow-from=*my_subnets*" in the powerdns/recursor.conf but it cause a problem, which is the internet servers like gmail servers cannot lookup for my reverse_zone. so all my PTR records are not available on the internet.
and if I change the "allow-from=" to 0.0.0.0/0 they became open_resolver for all IPs and any queries

I wonder if there is a solution to solve it like in the Bind9 which I can use "allow_query {trusted;}" for each zone in the named.conf.option. so I can control the Bind server to become open_resolver and just answer my own reverse_zone to the internet but no other question.

I would be glad if someone can help me.
thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0):

Apart from DNS you are using, its good to limit you resolver DNS servers to your network ranges, which will protect you from most of attacks.
On the other hand its good to open your authoritative nameservers to public.
my recommendation is to use Bind as your authoritative DNS server and use Unbound as your resolver server.